My table has a date column. I need a function that flags rows as True within the same group if there are a total of more than n rows within m months
I have an input table which I've called claim_data. It looks like this:
Record_ID,Event_ID,Policy No,Claim Name,Client_number's_PO,Claim No,Life_Assured,Client_number's_LA,Received Date,Incur Date,Product_code,Claim_type,Benefit/component_code,,
12,40,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,1,1,10053675,29/11/2019,10/11/2019,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,,
1,126,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,2,2,10003205,15/05/2020,4/05/2020,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,,
19,188,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,5,2,10003205,3/07/2020,6/06/2020,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,,
11,189,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,4,1,10053675,3/07/2020,7/06/2020,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,,
16,181,80069631,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,2,1,10073684,2/07/2020,7/06/2020,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,,
3,610,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,6,2,10003205,29/10/2020,7/10/2020,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,,
14,611,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,7,1,10053675,29/10/2020,18/10/2020,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,,
2,1014,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,8,2,10003205,20/12/2020,26/11/2020,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,,
17,1015,80069631,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,4,1,10073684,20/12/2020,4/12/2020,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,,
13,3687,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,9,1,10053675,21/09/2021,7/09/2021,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,,
18,3689,80069631,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,5,1,10073684,21/09/2021,7/09/2021,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,,
20,3690,80069631,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,6,1,10073684,21/09/2021,16/09/2021,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,,
6,5635,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,13,2,10003205,25/12/2021,8/11/2021,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,,
8,5637,80093241,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,1,1,10003213,25/12/2021,8/11/2021,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,,
43,5634,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,12,3,10003213,25/12/2021,8/11/2021,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,,
9,7544,80093241,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,2,1,10003213,19/04/2022,8/04/2022,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,,
41,7544,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,15,3,10003213,19/04/2022,8/04/2022,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,,
7,13004,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,18,2,10003205,21/02/2023,5/01/2023,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,,
42,13005,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,19,3,10003213,21/02/2023,5/01/2023,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,,
0,13097,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,21,2,10003205,24/02/2023,6/02/2023,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,,
10,12881,80093241,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,3,1,10003213,14/02/2023,6/02/2023,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,,
15,12880,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,16,1,10053675,14/02/2023,6/02/2023,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,,
44,13096,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,20,3,10003213,24/02/2023,6/02/2023,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,,
4,26741,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,27,2,10003205,6/12/2023,22/10/2023,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,,
5,24564,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,26,2,10003205,1/11/2023,28/10/2023,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,,

claim_data
This is what my function looks like.
def flag_date_within_m_months(group, col_label, col_date):
    group[col_date] = pd.to_datetime(group[col_date])
    group = group.sort_values(by=col_date)  # Sort by date
    group[col_label] = False
    
    # Create a rolling window to count claims
    for i in range(len(group)):
        current_date = group[col_date].iloc[i]
        window_start = current_date - pd.DateOffset(months=m)
        
        # Count the number of claims within the window
        count_within_window = group[(group[col_date] <= current_date) & (group[col_date] >= window_start)].shape[0]
        
        if count_within_window > n:
            # Flag all claims in the window
            group.loc[(group[col_date] <= current_date) & (group[col_date] >= window_start), col_label] = True
            print(f"Flagging claims between {window_start} and {current_date}")  # Debug output

    return group

However, when I use it the following way I don't get the results I expect. The aim of the following block of code is to flag rows where a customer ('Client_number's_PO') submits more than [n] claims on the same insurance benefit/component ('Benefit/component_code') within [m] months (incurred/event date) Upon manual checking there are many rows that should be flagged as True, but when I run this all rows are False.:
# Control parameters
n = 5
m = 6

# Create an index so that every row with the same 'Client_number's_PO' and 'Benefit/component_code' has the same index number.
claim_data["1. Index"] = claim_data_m.groupby(["Client_number's_PO", "Benefit/component_code"]).ngroup()

# Flag the rows based on the condition
claim_data["1"] = False
claim_data.groupby("1. Index").apply(flag_date_within_m_months, col_label="1", col_date="Incur Date")

Please help me fix this.
I tried what I described above, and I am expecting rows with more than n occurences in m months with the same 'Client_number's_PO' and 'Benefit/component_code' be flagged as True in column '1'. For example, for rows with the Client_number's_PO 10003205 and Benefit/component_code Rider03_04, I expect the results to be like this (TRUE if there are more than 5 claims within a 6 month window based on 'Incur Date'):
Record_ID,Event_ID,Policy No,Claim Name,Client_number's_PO,Claim No,Life_Assured,Client_number's_LA,Received Date,Incur Date,Product_code,Claim_type,Benefit/component_code,1,
12,40,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,1,1,10053675,29/11/2019,10/11/2019,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,FALSE,
1,126,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,2,2,10003205,15/05/2020,4/05/2020,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,TRUE,
19,188,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,5,2,10003205,3/07/2020,6/06/2020,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,TRUE,
11,189,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,4,1,10053675,3/07/2020,7/06/2020,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,TRUE,
16,181,80069631,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,2,1,10073684,2/07/2020,7/06/2020,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,TRUE,
3,610,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,6,2,10003205,29/10/2020,7/10/2020,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,TRUE,
14,611,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,7,1,10053675,29/10/2020,18/10/2020,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,TRUE,
2,1014,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,8,2,10003205,20/12/2020,26/11/2020,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,TRUE,
17,1015,80069631,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,4,1,10073684,20/12/2020,4/12/2020,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,TRUE,
13,3687,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,9,1,10053675,21/09/2021,7/09/2021,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,TRUE,
18,3689,80069631,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,5,1,10073684,21/09/2021,7/09/2021,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,TRUE,
20,3690,80069631,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,6,1,10073684,21/09/2021,16/09/2021,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,TRUE,
6,5635,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,13,2,10003205,25/12/2021,8/11/2021,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,TRUE,
8,5637,80093241,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,1,1,10003213,25/12/2021,8/11/2021,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,TRUE,
43,5634,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,12,3,10003213,25/12/2021,8/11/2021,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,TRUE,
9,7544,80093241,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,2,1,10003213,19/04/2022,8/04/2022,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,FALSE,
41,7544,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,15,3,10003213,19/04/2022,8/04/2022,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,FALSE,
7,13004,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,18,2,10003205,21/02/2023,5/01/2023,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,TRUE,
42,13005,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,19,3,10003213,21/02/2023,5/01/2023,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,TRUE,
0,13097,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,21,2,10003205,24/02/2023,6/02/2023,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,TRUE,
10,12881,80093241,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,3,1,10003213,14/02/2023,6/02/2023,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,TRUE,
15,12880,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,16,1,10053675,14/02/2023,6/02/2023,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,TRUE,
44,13096,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,20,3,10003213,24/02/2023,6/02/2023,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,TRUE,
4,26741,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,27,2,10003205,6/12/2023,22/10/2023,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,FALSE,
5,24564,80063166,Tr????ng An Diå÷??m,10003205,26,2,10003205,1/11/2023,28/10/2023,Rider03,RC,Rider03_04,FALSE,

expected results

Welcome to SO. To help people understand your question, please provide an example of  the input and output you hope to achieve with your function.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots (how to format code in posts). Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Please make a reproducible pandas example. A bunch of these columns seem to be irrelevant to the problem, so please remove them. Next, you can probably also reduce the number of rows and reduce n and m accordingly. Lastly, how are you loading the CSV into Pandas? Is that relevant to the problem, or can you just provide the loaded dataframe? (e.g. using df.to_dict('list').) See also [mre].

import pandas as pd

def flag_date_within_m_months(group, col_label, col_date, n_claims=5, months_window=6):
    """
    Flag rows within a group where there are more than n claims within m months.
    
    Parameters:
    -----------
    group : pandas.DataFrame
        Group of claims to analyze
    col_label : str
        Name of the column to store the flag
    col_date : str
        Name of the column containing dates
    n_claims : int, default=5
        Number of claims threshold
    months_window : int, default=6
        Number of months to look back
        
    Returns:
    --------
    pandas.DataFrame
        Group with added flag column
    """
    # Convert dates and sort
    group = group.copy()  # Prevent SettingWithCopyWarning
    group[col_date] = pd.to_datetime(group[col_date], format='%d/%m/%Y')
    group = group.sort_values(by=col_date)
    
    # Initialize flag column
    group[col_label] = False
    
    # For each date, look back m months and count claims
    for i in range(len(group)):
        current_date = group[col_date].iloc[i]
        window_start = current_date - pd.DateOffset(months=months_window)
        
        # Find all dates in the window
        mask = (group[col_date] >= window_start) & (group[col_date] <= current_date)
        claims_in_window = sum(mask)
        
        # If more than n claims in window, flag all claims in that window
        if claims_in_window > n_claims:
            group.loc[mask, col_label] = True
            
    return group

# Usage example:
def process_claims_data(df, n_claims=5, months_window=6):
    """
    Process the entire claims dataset to flag high-frequency claims.
    
    Parameters:
    -----------
    df : pandas.DataFrame
        Claims data
    n_claims : int, default=5
        Number of claims threshold
    months_window : int, default=6
        Number of months to look back
        
    Returns:
    --------
    pandas.DataFrame
        Processed dataframe with flags
    """
    # Create group index
    df = df.copy()
    df["group_index"] = df.groupby(["Client_number's_PO", "Benefit/component_code"]).ngroup()
    
    # Apply flagging function to each group
    result = df.groupby("group_index").apply(
        flag_date_within_m_months,
        col_label="flag",
        col_date="Incur Date",
        n_claims=n_claims,
        months_window=months_window
    ).reset_index(drop=True)
    
    return result


While this code may solve the problem, it's best to include a description of how. Often just a sentence or two is fine. Please [edit] to that. BTW, if you want more tips, check out [answer].

this works, thank you so much!
